# Setting an environment variable on the command line and making it affect two commands

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, environment-variables, command

This command works as expected

```bash
> TEST=`uuidgen` sh -c 'echo "$TEST"'
BE6DFB7B-D872-49D7-91E6-24D01644B0A2
> echo $TEST
[empty line]
```

It sets the `TEST` variable locally on the command line and it is echoed by the echo command. After this line is executed, `TEST` is no longer set.

This however

```bash
> TEST=`uuidgen` sh -c 'echo "$TEST"' && sh -c 'echo "$TEST"'                                          
52EFFEAA-D094-4FC3-8212-6A294918E265
[empty line]
```

has the `TEST` variable set for the first command, but not the command after the `&&`.
I want it to be set for *both* commands. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You could run both commands with the same shell:

```
TEST=`uuidgen` sh -c 'echo "$TEST" && echo "$TEST"'
```

Comment: I would prefer not to use that method, in my actual case I'm running two `yarn` not `sh`. Running two yarn inside `sh` seems inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't** want a variable assignment to be temporary (i.e. for just one command) then make the assignment on a separate line.

Some examples of different kinds of variable assignments:

1. ```
   TEST=foo echo "$TEST"
   ```

   This will **temporarily** assign the value `foo` to variable `TEST` (**and** temporarily export TEST) for **ONLY** that single `echo` command.  Afterwards, it reverts to whatever value (and export status) it had before - unset if it had no value.
2. ```
   TEST=foo
   echo "$TEST"
   NEWTEST="$TEST"
   ```

   In this example, TEST has the value `foo` until either the shell exits (e.g. logout or end of the script), or it is explicitly unset, or a new value assigned, so NEWTEST ends up with the same value (foo) as TEST.

   TEST is not exported, so is not available in the environment of programs executed from this shell.
3. If you want the variable to be available in the environment of executed programs, you need to export it.

   e.g.

   ```
   export TEST=foo
   ```

   or:

   ```
   TEST=foo
   export TEST
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `export TEST=bla` to make `TEST` variable for your whole shell session.

```
$ export TEST="coincoin"
$ echo $TEST
coincoin
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test is ${TEST}"
$ ./test.sh 
Test is coincoin
```

Comment: No, I don't want to make it an exported variable, I want it to live just for the duration of the line

Comment: @KlasMellbourn You could put the `export` and both commands in `( )`, so they run under a subshell. But that'd also prevent other things (other variable settings etc) from affecting the main shell.